# Stolen phone samsung s9+

Tags: lost-phone, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Yesterday I lost my phone (s9+) in a coffee shop. After atleast 3 hours of not knowing I lost it. I immediately tried to find it via samsung find my phone unfortunately it has no sim card and was not connected to a wifi. so i just tried to lock it via samsung account. My question is is it still possible for the thief to reformat and all to use the phone. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to review other questions with with the "lost-phone" tag. You also made no mention of a Google account being on the device... So assuming not, and no SIM and no WiFi connected, then of course the device could just be factory reset and used by anyone or sold. If you have an active Google account on the device, then Factory Reset Protection may prevent any potential thief from using/profiting from your device.

Comment: Before I was able to logged in to my samsung account the lost phone has its usual lock set ups..my finger print and iris and facial recognition and a 13 digit password. Would that help?

Comment: if that's a Samsung specific thing maybe, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for that person to reformat the phone by going into the recovery or going through factory reset in settings, but if you report your phone stolen, the IMEI won't allow that person to access the network towers. They can however use WiFi to get on the internet though.